# How to allocate OpenCV Mat/Image on CUDA pinned memory?

Tags: opencv, memory

So I'm using OpenCV `cv::Mat` to read/write file. But since they allocate using normal memory, transfering data to the GPU is slow.

Is there any way to make OpenCV use pinned memory (`cudaMallocHost` or `cudaHostAlloc`) by default? Memory size consumption is not a concern.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a9fa74fb14362d87cb183453d2441948f

Comment: Okay, so I should create a wrapper class that handle memory allocation, then use that cv::Mat() constructor. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
cv::Mat::setDefaultAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::getAllocator (cv::cuda::HostMem::AllocType::PAGE_LOCKED));
```

which will change the default allocator to use cuda pinned memory

Or for shared memory use

```
cv::Mat::setDefaultAllocator(cv::cuda::HostMem::getAllocator (cv::cuda::HostMem::AllocType::SHARED));
```